# Is rollback + custom mod flag the correct way to deal with robo-reviewers who pass obviously bad edits?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

The edit in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21959095 - as you can see, the "grammer" was tidied up but the "formatting" hosed a large part of the code in the question. I've rolled it back, but the reviewers who approved this edit deserve a time-out IMO. Is raising a custom moderator flag on the question, explaining what happened, the correct way to bring it to the mods' attention?

Comment: Maybe we could just auto-reject suggestions which misspell "grammar" as "grammer" in the comment?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Moderators have the ability to do an after-the-fact rejection of bad edits, but only if no edits have been performed since the one we want to reject. These rejections roll back the edit, change the status from accepted to rejected for the editor, and can activate an automatic editing ban if they reach a certain threshold.

Therefore, if you see a really terrible accepted suggested edit that should cause us to look into the editor and all reviewers, I'd recommend flagging it with a custom flag and not rolling it back. If you roll it back, we won't have the option of applying a rejection to it. However, we'll still be able to review everyone involved and apply manual bans, if necessary.

Comment: I'd probably add that if the post is vandalised or otherwise left in a completely unreadable state then do roll it back and flag for moderator review. But yeah, if it's just an "interesting"/"curious" edit but not directly harmful, just flagging instead of rolling back is a suitable option.

Comment: That is good to know!

Answer (score 6):

I would think that raising the flag would be the preferred solution as it gets the issue to the moderators without having to bring unneeded attention to the post and people in question from a meta post.

Once they get to the flag they should be able to see everything that happened from the posts history as long as the flag is clear enough as to what they should be looking for. As Jon Clements pointed out in a comment the more information that you can provide in the flag increases the chance of it being handled correctly.

Comment: I'd just note that every little bit of info that fits in the flag dialog helps... For instance in this case - "the suggested edit removed an entire codeblock from the post with no visible reason why"...